# Redis key naming conventions?

Tags: redis, naming-conventions

What is the standard naming convention for keys in redis? I've seen values separated by `:`, but I'm not sure what the standard convention is.

For a user, would you do something like:`user:00`

If the user's id was `00`

Are you able to query for just the beginning of the key to return all users?

I'm mainly just hoping to avoid any future problems by researching how that work for people and why they chose them.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

> What are the normal naming convention for keys in redis? I've seen
> values separated by : but I'm not sure what the normal convention is,
> or why.

Yes, colon sign `:` is a convention when naming keys. In [this](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) tutorial on redis website is stated: *Try to stick with a schema. For instance "object-type:id:field" can be
a nice idea, like in "user:1000:password". I like to use dots for
multi-words fields, like in "comment:1234:reply.to".*

> Are you able to query for just the beginning of the key to return all
> users?

If you mean something like directly querying for all keys which starts with `user:` there is a [keys](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command for that. This command should be however used only for debugging purpose since it's [O(N)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) because it's searching through all keys stored in database.

More appropriate solution for this problem is to create dedicated key, let's name it `users`, which will store all the users keys, for example, in [list](http://redis.io/commands#list) or [set](http://redis.io/commands#set) data structure.

Comment: It's not a convention, however it's similar to the URI-format which makes it common everywhere else.

Comment: @Gustav glancing at the URI-format wiki page, I can't figure out how this redis de facto standard is anything like the URI-format. Can you explain?

Comment: I'm talking about `urn:example:animal:ferret:nose` on that wiki page.

Comment: `scan` is not option @EranH., it is the best practice to iterate keys. `scan` is  used in order to incrementally iterate over a collection of elements.

Comment: @yojimbo87 So there will be two command lets say first is to creating key like - user:808021:password = XYZ and second one is to put the key in registry or index ( set ), but what will happen when one command executed successfully and other gets failed means keys got created but not get entry in registry.

Comment: @LoveToCode You can use transaction which should guarantee that either all or none of the operations will be executed.

Comment: I also noticed that Redis Desktop Manager (a Redis client tool) also treats colon ':' as separator, and displays multiple keys grouped together

Comment: I'm of the opinion that the unique value be last. Makes it easy to do something like: `$redis->delete($redis->keys('user:password:*'));`

Comment: @Crayons not sure how often you have such a use case except during development (when you're not sure what fields you want to store). In production, your diagnoses/surgery will most often be at the level of a class instance (i.e., a particular `user` or `vehicle`)

Comment: How about two words in a name?

Answer (score 44):

We use a colon (:) as namespace separator and a hash (#) for id-parts of keys, e.g.:

```
logistics:building#23
```

Comment: What is the best name convention if you have more keys like locale, category etc ? {resource}:{key}#{value},{key}#{value} => texts:locale#en,category#15 ? Or you have some other suggestion ?

Comment: In my example, "building" is just the name of the "collection", and 23 is the custom "id". If you have a composite id with locale=en and category=15, then the actual id could be {en,15}, so namespace:texts#{en,15} , or to be more verbose: namespace:texts#{locale=en,category=15}. But this is just an idea, I have never used it like this. Be careful not to change the order of the id-elements, because the key will not be found of course. Actually, instead of encoding such complexity in your key names, consider using redis data structures instead. Have a look at https://redis.io/topics/indexes

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could make things more readable in a way. Depending on what data you encode into the keys, you might need to escape/preprocess one more character ("#") though.

Answer (score 24):

A convention seems to be colon (:) **but** I'm a web developer so I personally prefer slash (/) for the separator. Slash is already so important separator within URLs which are meant to be [Uniform Resource Locators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) so kind of keys for resources. Why to take a different approach with colon (:)? Does it help anything?

Consider this example:

We have an [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API for toy objects. There is a one:

```
http://example.com/api/toy/234
```

Where we have it stored? We use Redis and slashes so the key is obvious:

```
toy/234
```

This is the unique key for the toy. The key can now be used also on client side:

```
{
    key: "toy/234",
    color: "red",
    url: function () {
        return API_BASE_URL + this.key;
    }
}
```

An user requests an object with key `toy/666`. How to get it from Redis? A Node.js related example:

```
redis.get(key, function reply_callback(error, toystring) {
    var toy = JSON.parse(toystring);
    ...
}
```

No need to convert slashes to colons and vice versa. Convenient, don't you think?

**Warning: always ensure that user is able to access only things you intended.** The raw URL-to-key approach above is able to fetch `user/1/password` as well, as noted by commentators. This should not be a problem if you use Redis as a public read-only cache.

Comment: … convenient, and almost *disgustingly* insecure. You're begging to get `curl http://example.com/api/user/1/password`'d, or similar. (Just sayin'.)

Comment: Colons, hashes and slashes can be used to designate different levels of nesting, e.g. `User#23:uploads:my/path/to/file.ext`

Comment: Please, never take user input as a key into the database.

Comment: I like how you thought you prefer slashes because you are a web developer.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE Thanks, added note about the insecurities. Do you see any problem in this approach if Redis is used as public read-only cache?

Comment: @HectorOrdonez Yeah, Unix (Linux, macOS) paths have probably much to do with it too :)

Comment: You got my vote, but in this case it would be a [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) and not a URL.

Comment: @DanielSantos Thanks for the detail. I thought about this. Yes, URL is a URI scheme. URI is more generic concept. Is it too generic here? Some URIs do not seem to use slashes to denote hierarchy, take for example `tel:+1-816-555-1212`. [URI RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) recommends slash for hierarchy but does not enforce it. Therefore I thought it is slightly easier to compare redis keys to URLs than URIs.

Comment: @AkseliPalén However, a Redis key name need not use the slash character to delimit hierarchy.  In fact, some people use the colon for this.  That being said, I haven't closely analyzed and compared the rules for each to be certain they are "legally" compatible.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there really are widespread "best practices" for Redis key naming yet.

I've experimented with using ASCII NUL characters as my separators (since Redis and Python are both 8-bit clean).  It looks a little ugly if you're looking at raw keys, but the idea is to hide it behind an abstraction layer. Colon and pipe symbols are obvious alternatives so long as the components of your name space are either guaranteed not to use them or you're willing to encode each component as necessary.  However, if you'd be encoding them then you'd want develop the abstraction layer and avoiding viewing raw keys anyway ... which brought me right back to just using \0 in my reasoning.

I'll be interesting in seeing if any other opinions are articulated on this.

Comment: Your approach could be compared to using tab-separated values instead of CSV. Tabs are less likely to require preprocessing/escaping, but sometimes can be more tricky to work with. For computers it doesn't matter, but we, humans, might be more prone to mistakes if we need to manually view/edit special characters. Just my 2 cents, something to be considered when making such decisions.

Answer (score 3):

For your usecase it seems to me [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset)/[HGET](https://redis.io/commands/hget) would be a better fit. There is also [HKEYS](https://redis.io/commands/hkeys) command.

All those commands have same complexity as GET/SET/KEYS, so why not use them?

You could have this structure then:

- users > 00 > value
- users > 01 > value

or:

- users:username > 00 > value
- users:username > 01 > value

Just extract user's ID and use it as a hash key. I personally prefer this approach as it feels nicer and also you can easily query for existing user IDs.