# "Grouping" data in Redis

Tags: redis

I have recently been looking at Redis and it seems almost perfect as I am doing something that mostly needs key-value based data structures.

As someone who has mostly used MySQL as a database I have got used to grouping data in tables and am quite confused as when reading about Redis I have seen no mention of tables or any other way of grouping data. Does this mean there is no concept of tables in Redis?

For example if I had a simple website where users could post comments about other users in a relational database I could have a table "users" and a table "comments", how would this be done using Redis?

Hopefully this is clear enough, thanks in advance.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965451/redis-key-naming-conventions which I think answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, redis is a super-powered key-value store, not a relational database. There are no tables.

However, something can be done. Take a look at [LamerNews](https://github.com/antirez/lamernews). It's a hackernews-like site that uses redis as its data store.

Answer (score 1):

Users can be stored in a SET or LIST in REDIS.

User comments have to be stored in a HASH, with keys as commenter:commented and value would be the comment. So if user1 comments on user2 some text like "Hello hw do u do?", then our HASH which we can call as UserComments will have key and values as :

Key=  user1:user2
value = "Hello hw do u do?"

From the HASH you could any time get all the comments posted by users, also if you tokenized the key you would get commenter and commented.