# redis key-value what the limitation of key?

Tags: redis, key

```
set "as";b 1 is error 
key:  "as";b
value:   1
```

what is the naming rule of key?

Redis uses SDS to implement  string. Book says SDS can contain any construction of string

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact question - can you provide more information?

Answer (score 20):

A Redis key name can be *any* string as long as it is under 512MB. Other than that, there are no rules.

Answer (score 7):

Anything goes...  up to 512MB

http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-keys

other discussion on Redis key naming conventions

[Redis key naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965451/redis-key-naming-conventions)