# Redis PFADD to check a exists-in-set query

Tags: redis

I have a requirement to process multiple records from a queue. But due to some external issues the items may sporadically occur multiple times.
I need to process items only once

What I planned to use is PFADD into redis every record ( as a md5sum) and then  see if that returns success. If that shows no increment then the record is a duplicate else process the record.

This seems pretty straightforward , but I am getting too many false positives while using PFADD

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

Being the probabilistic data structure that it is, Redis' HyperLogLog exhibits 0.81% standard error. You can reduce (but never get rid of) the probability for false positives by using multiple HLLs, each counting a the value of a different hash function on your record.

Also note that if you're using a single HLL there's no real need to hash the record - just `PFADD` as is.

Alternatively, use a Redis Set to keep all the identifiers/hashes/records and have 100%-accurate membership tests with [`SISMEMBER`](http://redis.io/commands/sismember). This approach requires more (RAM) resources as you're storing each processed element, but unless your queue is really huge that shouldn't be a problem for a modest Redis instance. To keep memory consumption under control, switch between Sets according to the date and set an expiry on the Set keys (another approach is to use a single Sorted Set and manually remove old items from it by keeping their timestamp in the score).

Comment: Will SISMEMBER store all the "members" in memory  , I could have 10 Million md5 records per day , and I need to store it for a week

Comment: @Ram Redis is basically an in-memory database, the danger with sets would be that they do not play well with Redis cluster (which you may want to use at some point if you have lots of data). Overall, I would recommend a simple hash (set, hset).

Comment: @Ram - you'll need to use `SADD` to add members to the Set, `SISMEMBER` is only a membership test. And yes, all values will be kept in RAM - 70 million md5 values should be about 2GB of raw data.

Comment: @nha "the danger with sets would be that they do not play well with Redis cluster" - that's just not true. Sets work perfectly well, whether you're using Redis Cluster or standalone. In that sense, Sets aren't any different than Hashes.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Redis cluster implements a subset of Redis (http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#implemented-subset). Specifically see this quote "Commands performing complex multi-key operations like Set type unions or intersections are implemented as well as long as the keys all belong to the same node.", so I think this is worth noting that the behaviour of sets in Redis and Redis cluster is not the same. In that sense, they are different than hashes (although as long as you stay away from union/intersections they are the same and your answer is perfectly valid).

Comment: That quote is for all multi-key commands in the cluster, Sets are only given as a prominent example since their API is largely about that. Regardless, my proposal doesn't call for multi-key Set operations.

Answer (score 2):

In general in distributed systems you have to choose between processing items either :

- at most once
- at least once

Processing something exactly-once would be convenient however this is generally impossible.

That being said there could be acceptable workarounds for your specific use case, and as you suggest storing the items already processed could be an acceptable solution.

Be aware though that [PFADD](http://redis.io/commands/pfadd) uses HyperLogLog, which is fast and [scales but is approximate](http://antirez.com/news/75) about the count of the items, so in this case I do not think this is what you want.
However if you are fine with having a small probability of errors, the most appropriate data structure here would be a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) (as described [here for Redis](http://redis.io/topics/data-types)), which can be implemented in a very memory-efficient way.

A simple, efficient, and [recommended](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#use-hashes-when-possible) solution would be to use a simple redis key (for instance a hash) storing a boolean-like value ("0", "1" or "true", "false") for instance with the [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/HSET) or [SET with the NX](http://redis.io/commands/SET) option instruction. You could also put it under a [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6965451/1327651) if you wish to. It has the added benefit of being able to expire keys also.

It would avoid you to use a set (not the [SET](http://redis.io/commands/SET) command, but rather the [SINTER](http://redis.io/commands/SINTER), [SUNION](http://redis.io/commands/SUNION) commands), which doesn't necessarily work well with [Redis cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#implemented-subset) if you want to scale to more than one node. [SISMEMBER](http://redis.io/commands/SISMEMBER) is still fine though (but lacks some features from hashes such as time to live).

If you use a hash, I would also advise you to pick a hash function that has fewer chances of [collisions than md5](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/) (a collision means that two different objects end up with the same hash).

An alternative approach to the hash would be to assign an uuid to every item when putting it in the queue (or a squuid if you want to have some time information).

Comment: I think HSET is a good solution, also a normal SET with the NX option is a good option and you can add an expiration time if the items in the queue doesnt repeat after a period

Comment: @PerroVerd exactly (I thought I wrote about it but got distracted). The basic Redis operations are usually good enough (the only thing is to avoid scanning the whole database, and keep the relationship between keys simple).

Comment: @nha using a "boolean" Hash instead of a Set is not only awkward but also more wasteful since you suggest storing also the fasle/0 entries (funnily enough, Redis' Sets are implemented with Hashes internally). Sets are **the** natural choice for membership tests and your last edit to your answer only degrades it - the part about hash collisions is actually very correct but is now totally lost in inaccuracies. Lastly, Sets are entirely cluster-safe, it is multi-key cross-slot operations that aren't supported regardless of the data structure.

Comment: @ItamarHaber 1 - thanks for explaining the downvote (assuming it is you) 2 - "it is multi-key cross-slot operations that aren't supported regardless of the data structure" yes, this was the intent to explain that in my last edit 3 - I do not suggest to store false value, maybe I need to rephrase that. 4 - I don't think I mentioned anything about "cluster-safe", only warned about the difference in behaviour between Redis and Redis cluster. I otherwise agree that Sets are natural for membership tests for Redis (still not so sure about Redis cluster).