# How to get all 'key namespaces' (object types) in Redis?

Tags: redis

As we may know, [good naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965451/redis-key-naming-conventions) for Redis keys is `"object-type:id"`

How to get all key namespaces (symbols before `:`)?

E.g.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "bar:1"
2) "baz:1"
3) "baz:3"
4) "foo:1"
5) "foo:2"
6) "baz:2"
```

I want a command like

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 0 MATCH "(^\w+):" COUNT 10
1) "6"
2) "foo"
3) "bar"
4) "baz"
```

But seems like [MATCH](https://redis.io/commands/scan#the-match-option) option of SCAN command does not support PCRE pattern syntax.

In real, I got

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SCAN 0 MATCH "(^\w+):" COUNT 10
1) "6"
2) (empty list or set)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: As far as I can see, `SCAN ... MATCH` wouldn't give you what you wanted even if you used the right style of pattern, because it's just a post-filter on a set of results, and doesn't manipulate or group the names in any way. The question seems a good one, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an index key and add each namespace to it every time you add a new key:
`SADD "namespaces" "foo"`. But there would be problem with deleting them, as you'd have to check if the deleted object was the last of it's type.

The second option would be creating a [module](https://redis.io/documentation#redis-modules-api) (if you're using Redis >= 4.0) with a command that you could use to add and remove said keys, that would have it's own type in which it would store object-type counters (so it wouldn't have to call `KEYS *` which is quite slow). The problem here would be if you had key expiration, or oom key deletion configured. The counter would be incorrect once a key gets deleted by Redis itself.

The third option is to create a module with one command that would call `KEYS *`, then get the first part of the key and add it to a hash map/dictionary (using `RedisModuleDict`) and then return it using `RedisModule_ReplyWithString(ctx, str)` in a loop

I think that you could also write it in Lua instead of creating a module, but a module written in C is probably going to be faster... and I don't know Lua so I won't be able to help you there.

You could always write a simple script in bash that would get the object-type from each key and `SADD` it to a temporary key then read it, print and delete afterwards, but that's the same as the third option but slower and has to use a temporary key which might be used by some other script or something.